# Automatic generation of rules in laravel from migration

Tags: laravel

When I describe in database migration some field, that it must be at maximum 256 characters long I have to describe this in model too, so that when user enters 257 characters database does not generate exception.

May be there is a better way to do it?

Comment: you should not do it inside your model , but rather do it in your FormRequest class or with validation in your controller.

Comment: It is very convenient to describe basic rules (like max length) inside model and other rules in FormRequest.

Comment: This is essentially built in to Eloquent as your database should produce an error which will in turn cause Laravel to throw an exception.

Comment: A second option is to do it inside the boot() method on your appserviceprovider. You can set the schema for all fields. But this is not really good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for this would be to use request validation in your controller when you submit your form. I can give you an example of this

Firstly make a request using artisan

```
php artisan make:request MyRequest
```

This will make a file called MyRequest.php in App/Http/Requests

Add your validation rules to the rules() function

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'text_field_name' => 'required|string|max:256'
    ];
}
```

You can find all the validation options here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#available-validation-rules

You then just need to apply the request to the function that accepts your POST data. The Data will be validated before the function is run, ensuring that you will not get database exceptions from string length

In your controller

```
public function myPostController(\App\Http\Requests\MyRequest $request)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a small tool for that:

[Validation for Laravel - Convert your Migration into Validation Rules](https://validationforlaravel.com)

If you give something like this:

```php
function (Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('first_name', 100);
    $table->string('last_name', 100);
    $table->string('email');
    $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained();
    $table->text('bio')->nullable();
    $table->enum('gender', ['m', 'f', 'd']);
    $table->date('birth');
    $table->year('graduated');
    $table->float('body_size');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('children_count')->nullable();
    $table->integer('account_balance');
    $table->unsignedInteger('net_income');
    $table->boolean('send_newsletter')->nullable();
};
```

You'll get:

```php
[
    'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:100'],
    'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:100'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:255'],
    'address_id' => ['required', 'exists:addresses,id'],
    'bio' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1'],
    'gender' => ['required', 'string', 'in:m,f,d'],
    'birth' => ['required', 'date'],
    'graduated' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1901', 'max:2155'],
    'body_size' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'children_count' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'min:0', 'max:255'],
    'account_balance' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:-2147483648', 'max:2147483647'],
    'net_income' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:0', 'max:4294967295'],
    'send_newsletter' => ['nullable', 'boolean']
];
```